# The matrix form of a representation of $S_3$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am going through some notes on group theory, and one problem states:

> Consider the three-dimensional representation of $S_3$ constructed as follows: Choose a basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $\sigma\in S_3$ acts as:
>
> $D(\sigma):v_i\rightarrow v_{\sigma(i)}$

We are asked to find a matrix form of this representation, so I am assuming that the matrix for each $\sigma$ would be the corresponding permutation matrix. We then consider the invariant subspace $V_1=\langle v_1+v_2+v_3\rangle$. We are asked:

> Find the matrix form of the representation acting on $V_1^{\perp}$. Is this reducible?

I believe that then $V_1^{\perp}$ is given by the span of $v_1-v_2$ and $v_1-v_3$. However, I am unsure what exactly the question means. Do I have to change the basis of the representation to be in the basis vectors of $V_1$ and $V_1^{\perp}$? In that case if I denoted $w_1=v_1+v_2+v_3$, $w_2=v_1-v_3$ and $w_3=v_1-v_2$ then the first column of $D(\sigma)$ would be $(1;0;0)$ and the second two columns would depend on $\sigma$. We can see however that the first element of each would have to be zero,  by considering how the permutations could affect $w_1=v_1-v_2$ and $w_2=v_1-v_3$ and working out that neither of them will be mapped to a linear combination involving $w_1$. Does this seem like the right thing to do?

As for whether or not it is reducible, would I have to find some intertwiner that commutes with each matrix element and show that this is nonzero/not an isomorphism?

Comment: Reducible means here that there is a one-dimensional subspace of $V_1^{\perp}$ invariant under the group action.  Hint for deciding whether or not this is the case: eigenvalues.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for your reply. A matrix with an eigenvalue has one-dimensional invariant subspaces corresponding to each linearly independent eigenvector of that eigenvalue, so would I need to show that there exists (or cannot exist) some $v\in V_1^{\perp}$ which is an eigenvector for each $\sigma\in S_3$?

Comment: I computed all the eigenvectors and found that the only simultaneous eigenvector of all $\sigma\in S_3$ was $w_1$ which is not in $V_1^{\perp}$. Thus $V_1^{\perp}$ cannot be reducible since any invariant proper subspace would be 1-dimensional and would provide it with an eigenvector. Is there though a more elegant way of showing that there cannot be a simultaneous eigenvector other than manually computing all of them?